# Парсить новостные сайты, чем?

Tags: парсер, поиск-библиотек

Руководство поставило задачу, парсить новостные сайты и записывать свежие новости в текстовые файлы.
Сайтов нужно парсить несколько, новости от каждого сайта складывать в свою папочку. Так же по датам раскладывать по папкам.
Предполагается веб-сервис на PHP, который будет запускаться ручками или по крону.
Так же, возможно и виндовое приложение.
С чего начать? Всяко должно быть какие-то либы, которые упростят жизнь в данной разработке.
Надо паузу в обходе ставить, что бы под блок не попасть из-за большого кол-ва запросов.
Не перевыкачивать уже выкачанные новости.
Чистить от html тэгов, т.к. нужен только текст.
и т.д.
Явно до меня уже многие этот путь прошли.

Comment: BeautifulSoup .

Comment: Да, прошли. Вам надо почитать про LWP, ну и Perl. Там делов-то, минут на 40, максимум... И по возможности, не использовать готовые продукты, если есть вариант узнать что-то новое, и попробовать что-то создать, пусть и велосипед.

Comment: Если новостные сайт поддерживают RSS, то и парсить не нужно будет